# osmbonuspack dismiss Bubble

Tags: android, osmdroid

I have an activity A which has a map (using osmbonuspack for Android). I click on a point from the map and a bubble appears. This bubble has a detail button that when clicked I go to Activity B.

When I go back from Activity B to Activity A, the bubble is still opened. How can I force the bubble to disappear?

Comment: Have you tried making a call in onResume to close any open bubbles?